# Getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when no extra parenthesis on left

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my SQL query:

```
select hck.hacker_id, hck.name, cnt
from (
    Hacker as hck 
    inner join (
       Select hacker_id, count(challenge_id) as cnt 
       from Challenges 
       group by hacker_id
    ) chl_count on hck.hacker_id = chl_count.hacker_id
) having cnt = max(cnt) or 
cnt in (select cnt 
        from chl_count 
        group by cnt 
        having count(hacker_id) = 1) 
order by cnt desc, hck.hacker_id asc;
```

Here Hackers has schema:

```
Hackers(name, hacker_id)
```

And Challenges has schema

```
Challenges(hacker_id, ,challenge_id)
```

I don't see any missing parenthesis in the query. So, what is wrong? Also, other syntaxes such as commas are correct as well.

Comment: I think error parenthesis in (Hacker. But You writed query incorrect. Because HAVING without GROUP BY, MAX(cnt) also. Write, please, your test case with correct result.

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and expected output derived from that sample. An explanation of the business rules you're trying to implement wouldn't go amiss either. It's easier for you to tell us what you want to do than it is to reverse engineer your requirements from some broken code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are new in Oracle SQL.

You can't do this: "`..FROM (Hacker as hck inner join) ..`" but you can do it like this:

```
WITH chl_count
     AS (  SELECT hacker_id, COUNT (challenge_id) AS cnt
             FROM Challenges
         GROUP BY hacker_id)
  SELECT hck.hacker_id, hck.name, cnt
    FROM Hacker hck INNER JOIN chl_count ON hck.hacker_id = chl_count.hacker_id
  HAVING    cnt = (select max(challenge_id) from Challenges)
         OR cnt IN (  SELECT cnt
                        FROM chl_count
                      WHERE hacker_id= 1)
ORDER BY cnt DESC, hck.hacker_id ASC;
```

It should work now.

Comment: `HAVING ` without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Tejash, as pure syntax, you can have `HAVING` clause without `GROUP BY` clause. As logic, it may depends if it's correct.

Comment: now it's giving error `FROM chl_count 
* 
ERROR at line 9: 
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
` even  though chl_count is there

Comment: @ShantanuShinde Oh .. you can't use like that. I will update the query with a solution. I just added the `with` clause. It will help you. Please read about it in order to understand better.

Comment: that error gone, but not I get `OR cnt IN ( SELECT cnt 
* 
ERROR at line 8: 
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression `

Comment: @ShantanuShinde , try it again now. I modified it.

Comment: @ShantanuShinde, I edited again. I created the structure and from the code point of view, it's working. Hope that it's returning what you need. Also, please be aware that stackoverflow it's for guiding you, not writing your code. The last modifications where very easy to find/deduce/conclude .. so please try to understand what is there.